# If-Else Issue In Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, addition, subtraction

I am doing a conditional statement in javascript. When the user enters a value in the input box "Collect", its value together with the value from input box "CurBal" will perform an addition and put the answer in the input box named "Balance".

If the user enters a value in the input box "Deposit", its value will be substracted from the "CurBal" and the difference will also be reflected (supposedly) in the "Balance"

I have this code:

```
var collect = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Collect").value) ||0;
var dep     = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Deposit").value) ||0;
var curr    = parseFloat(document.getElementById("CurBal").value) ||0;
var bal     = document.getElementById("Balance");

if (collect.value = true)
{
 bal.value = (collect + curr).toFixed(2)
 bal       = document.getElementById("Balance");
}

else if (dep.value = true)
{
 bal.value = (curr - dep).toFixed(2)
 bal       = document.getElementById("Balance");
}
```

The HTML:

```
<tr>
 <td> &nbsp;Collections: </td>
 <td> &nbsp; <input onchange="addNumbers()" type="text" id="Collect" name="Collect" value="" /> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td> &nbsp;Deposits:</td>
 <td> &nbsp;<input onchange="addNumbers()" type="text" id="Deposit" name="Deposit" value="" /> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td> &nbsp;Current Balance: </td>
 <td> &nbsp;<input onchange="addNumbers()" type="text" id="CurBal" name= "CurBal" value="<?php echo $all['balance']; ?>" readonly="readOnly" /> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td> &nbsp;Balance: </td>
 <td> &nbsp;<input type="text" id="Balance" name="Balance" value="" readonly="readOnly" /> </td>
</tr>
```

But, its just performing the first condition correctly. If I entered a value in the input box "Deposit", it isn't subtracting the value from "CurBal", its just copying the value from "CurBal".

What should be removed or added or changed? Thank you for the help

Additional info: The user can only EITHER enter a value to "Collect" OR "Balance".

Comment: `=` is for assignment, `==` or `===` for comparison.

Comment: if I put "if (collect.value == true)", there is NO "answer" in the input box "Balance"

Comment: That's probably because there is a value in both `collect` and `dep`, and those values do not evaluate to `true`, so neither `if` condition is satisfied. Try changing the `if` conditions to: `if (collect.value != 0)`

Comment: What are you trying to check with that condition?

Comment: Also, what about `curr`? You are checking whether the `collect` textbox has a value, but you don't validate whether the `curr` textbox has a value.

Comment: curr has a value which came from the database

Comment: @thefourtheye, I am trying to see if the input box has a value so that I can perform the operation. >.<

Comment: Collect, dep, and curr are already the values.  They don't have a value property.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED PER COMMENTS BELOW**

```
// Collect is now a number
var collect = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Collect").value) ||0;

// dep is now a number
var dep     = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Deposit").value) ||0;

// Cur is now a number
var curr    = parseFloat(document.getElementById("CurBal").value) ||0;

// bal is now pointing to an element
var bal     = document.getElementById("Balance");


// What are you trying to compare here? That bal !== 0 perhaps?
// Collect is a number, so we can do the compare here.
if (collect !== 0)  {
 bal.value = (collect + curr).toFixed(2)


 // Dep, on the other hand, is pointing to an element
 // so we use the property here
 // The leading '+' is a quick way to turn the string value (dep.value is a string)
 // into a number.
} else if (+dep.value !== 0) {
 bal.value = (curr - dep).toFixed(2)
}
```

** Notes **
The line:

```
if (collect !== 0)  {
```

can be written shorter as

```
if (collect)  {
```

but I always recommend writing the most readable version that describes exactly what you mean.

Comment: I am trying to see if the the input box has a value so that I can perform the addition or subtraction. It was supposed to either add or subtract and then the "answer" will be put in the "bal"

Comment: @user3373430 - Updated my answer with a little bit of explanation.

Comment: Sir @Jeremy, thank you. But still, the first condition is performing correctly. The 2nd condition isn't. it is only copying the value from input box "curbal". >.<

Comment: It's still copying the values from "curbal". Additional info, the user can just enter a value to the input box "Balance" OR "Deposit". Just ONE at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
if (collect.value = true)
{
 bal.value = (collect + curr).toFixed(2)
 bal       = document.getElementById("Balance");
}

else if (dep.value == true)
{
 bal.value = (curr - dep).toFixed(2)
 bal       = document.getElementById("Balance");
}
```

It sounds as though you need this:

```
if (collect.value = true)
{
 bal.value = (collect + curr).toFixed(2)
 bal       = document.getElementById("Balance");
}

if (dep.value == true)
{
 bal.value = (curr - dep).toFixed(2)
 bal       = document.getElementById("Balance");
}
```

You have an `else if` condition, so if `collect.value` is true, your other conditions won't run.

Of note - you also are performing assignment in your `if` statements, when in fact, you should be checking for equality. In fact, you don't even need to do that; you can do:

```
if (collect.value)
{
...
}

if (dep.value)
{
...
}
```

Comment: if i put "if (collect.value)" or "if (collect.value = true)", I'm not getting any "answer" in the input box "Balance". that is why I put "if (collect.value = true)", because with that, I am getting an "answer". Its confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning `true` to `collect.value` in the first `if` test. The value of an assignment expression is the value assigned; in this case `true`. Thus the first test will always succeed. You should use `==` or `===` for comparison tests. (The first operator will convert types if necessary; the `===` operator will only succeed if the current data types are already the same).

For boolean values, it's better to use `if (collect.value)` (etc.) rather than `if (collect.value == true)`.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing double equal sign in if condition.
try changing the condition.

```
if (collect.value != 0)

else if (dep.value != 0)
```

Comment: if i put ==, Im not getting any results. Also, when I tried your solution, the first condition is performing correctly (the addition). But the subtraction is not right. It just copied the value from the curbal. >.<

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var collect = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Collect").value) ||0;
var dep     = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Deposit").value) ||0;
var curr    = parseFloat(document.getElementById("CurBal").value) ||0;
var bal     = document.getElementById("Balance");

if (collect != 0)
{
 bal.value = (collect + curr).toFixed(2)
 bal       = document.getElementById("Balance");
}

else if (dep != 0)
{
 bal.value = (curr - dep).toFixed(2)
 bal       = document.getElementById("Balance");
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Preston S. I tried your solution, the first condition is performing correctly (the addition). But the subtraction is not right. It just copying the value from the curbal

Comment: @user3373430 please include your html for further analysis